# ASP.NET Core Identity UserManager Finds non-existant user with FindByEmailAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been trying to use ASP.NET Core Identity in order to check for existing users in my db and when I call FindByEmailAsync or other Find methods on UserManager class it finds entity with Id even though AspNetUsers DB table is empty

I've doublechecked my Startup.cs file, because I'm almost sure that has to be something with DI. But I use this EntityManager in my service class and this class is being registered as Scoped.

It doesn't matter what i type in parameter, always returns some entity:

[image: Checking with any string]

My Startup DI configurations:

My User (derives from IdentityUser):
[image: Checking with any string]

My service registration (where I use UserManager via DI):
[image: Service container registration]

I expect these methods not to find any user entities, but for some reason it always returs non-null values.

Might be the Identity caching or DI problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FindByEmailAsync` method returns a `Task`, not a user. If you check the type of the `userExists` variable, you will see that it's of type `Task<>`. So, the method doesn't return a user with id 70, but a `Task` with id 70. If you modify this line:

```cs
var userExists = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("rasfafasf");
```

by adding `await`:

```cs
var userExists = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("rasfafasf");
```

you will get an actual result of a Task, which is the user with that email (`null` in your case).